# can not link app data to SD with s2e

Tags: cyanogenmod, mount, s2e

cm10.1, galaxy gio :

I have problem with "memory full" message after I set DATA mount-point to sdcard

no problem with other options ... just with data.

what should I do ?! :(

Answer (score -2):

i think rooting is required. try after rooting ur mobile then u can open the app